# ¿Como cambio el comportamiento de la tecla Esc en VsCode?

Tags: linux, vscode, configuración, linux-mint

Invertí el comportamiento de [Bocq Mayus] y [Esc] de la siguiente manera:

sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc

-key < ESC> { [ Escape ] };
+key < ESC> { [ Caps_Lock ] };
. . .
-key < CAPS> { [ Caps_Lock ] };
+key < CAPS> { [ Escape ] };

Pero en vscode el comportamiento de las teclas no se ha invertido en todos los casos.
Por ejemplo, cuando le doy buscar [ctrl+f] y luego le doy a [Caps_lock] para ocultar, no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modificando el archivo de configuración de vscode:

vim ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json

y añadiendo:

"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode",